# Enabling TLS 1.0? Cannot communicate securely with peer: no connection encryption algorithms

Tags: security, curl, amazon-ec2, libcurl, server

For over a year I have been running a photo based website that allows customers to order prints, which are subsequently fulfilled by a printing company.  Orders are posted in XML format to a designated URL.  Recently it has come to my attention that the orders are not being post and I have found the following error when examining the server logs:

```
 [Mon Dec 01 21:17:38 2014] [error] [client XXX] cURL error: [35] Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
```

The tech team for the printing company was able to provide me with some direction, but I remain confused.  Initially they informed me that the server currently supports SSLv2, SSLv3 and TLS 1.0 only, and that it was likely that we only have TLS 1.2 enabled on our end.  They claimed that nothing was changed on their end, and I personally know that nothing has been modified on ours for months.

When I originally encountered the problem I attempted to update the server packages, but this failed to resolve the problem.  Later I thought that perhaps the issue revolved around the security groups for the Amazon EC2 instance, but I am not entirely sure.  How would I go about enabling TLS 1.0, assuming it is not already enabled?  How would I check what transport layer securities and secure socket layers are currently enabled?  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you can route the traffic through an HTTP proxy, you can install Fiddler and see what is in the TLS negotiation info:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response @user18044.  I've been trying to use openssl to determine what is supported, but Fiddler appears to have greater functionality. How would i go about routing the traffic through the proxy?

Comment: That depends on what stack you're using. For .NET applications it's documented here: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp

Answer (score 0):

By default on most systems libcurl already speaks TLS 1.0 fine if that's what the server wants.

I rather suspect your problem is that the server insists on using a cipher for this URL that libcurl won't agree to. More specifically, I would suspect it is an RC4-using cipher and RC4 is deemed insecure and is disabled by default by libcurl.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Daniel, if this is the problem, how would I go about addressing the insecurities associated with cipher?